# Septic alarm went off. Pump running. Unknown valve in closed position. Is there DIY fix or tank needs to be drained?

Tags: plumbing, septic

Recently bought a home with septic system and alarm went off. I silenced it:

[image]

It seems it has been in continuous mode for at least last few months. First question - **Is this the expected mode or should it be in auto?**

Also, I checked what is under 3 covers:

[image]

What I believe to be "water level sensor" has hose (or wire) that does not go anywhere and the whole thing kinda floats in liquid underneath. Second question - **Is this detached hose expected (e.g. relic after past septic tank upgrades) or could explain why pump was left in continuous mode by previous owner?**

[image]

Third question, under far right covers is a valve - **what could be its purpose and why is it in closed position?**

[image]

I see that pump is running as there is visible water current under one of the covers. I believe this indicates that pump is running, Fourth question - **so what are some other possible troubleshooting steps I can take - has the problem been reduced to a clog somewhere?**

[image]

Comment: You've got too many variables here. You really should get the information from the previous owners on who installed the system and have them come out and explain the system to you.

Comment: Notice the labels on the incoming wires, you have an aerator and a pump.  I'm guessing what you are seeing running is the aerator and not the pump.  Usually sewage pumps are under the water.

Comment: I'm guessing you have (at least) 2 tanks, the tank furthest from the house should be the effluent tank with the pump.  That is usually where the alarm is too.  The point of failures for me are usually either the pump, the wiring, or the float switch.

Comment: Get the documents from when the system was installed from whoever permits systems in your area (county/town board of health or similar department, typically) as you have a non-simple system with aeration, and multiple points of "well that looks odd" - I expect both the hose and the line with the closed valve have some function related to air, not water, given their size, but why the hose is cut off and why the valve is closed are things not easy to figure out without knowing what's supposed to be happening...

Comment: @rtaft you are right that is aerator, not pump (I verified that by toggling "aerator power" switch and it went off). I suppose this means I have to take a step back and verify if pump is bad.

Comment: @user389238 how did it go?

Comment: @rtaft I un-silenced alarm and it does not alarm me anymore. After your comment about aerator I tried "test pump" button and it engaged pump - so pump itself is good.  have reached out to the previous owner's company and they have not responded. Based on control board I am now wondering if that was "chlorine alarm"? do you know how to test them with multimeter to isolate which of the 3 alarms triggered it?

Comment: @user389238 There is nothing you can do it if it's not currently alarming.  The floats can be tested with a simple continuity tester (powered off and maybe disconnected first).  It looks like aerator septic systems require regular chlorine.